# how to get comments in the media with API instagram

Tags: instagram

I would like to get comments from
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/media_id/comments/?client_id=CLIENT_ID
*how do I know when there are comments posted, so I can retrieve the new comments without the old.
Does it avoid the duplication?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't get only new comments from instagram API.

What you can do — store all comments for each person and compare with current all comments which you'll reach from instagram for each person (be aware with limits)